# why does supported voices and language sample different from demo sample?

Tags: google-text-to-speech

I'm planning to purchase a text to speech that i could use for my youtube channel and i found something good [Filipino (Philippines)    WaveNet fil-PH  fil-PH-Wavenet-AFEMALE] on cloud flatform.

... but when you try it in the demo Put Text-to-Speech into action, it has a different voice with a weird accent. maybe its only an error that technical haven't notice. i've contacted someone on chat but i only manage to contact a sales representative and she also notice the error but she said that only the technical team could fix it. when you try the other text to speech demo sample for filipino voices they sound like a robot with a broken mic. it's different from what is advertise from different text to speech samples.